# Binding fragments in listview

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-listview, xamarin, mvvmcross

I have a MvvmCross Android application and let's say it contains some Fragment and ViewModel. I set the ViewModel for the Fragment inside `OnCreate` call of the Activity which hosts the fragment as it is shown at [N+1 Fragments Sample](https://github.com/MvvmCross/NPlus1DaysOfMvvmCross/blob/master/N-26-Fraggle/Rock.Droid/Views/FirstView.cs) All bindings inside the fragment work fine.

I also have another Activity with a view that contains MvxListView. The row template of the listview contains the fragment I described above. How can I set the ViewModel of the fragment so that bindings work correctly?

Comment: Did you get this to work? I am trying to do exactly the same thing

Comment: I would not suggest using fragments as a row templates.

Comment: @AlexSorokoletov Why?

Comment: Can't find you exact argument (and I know how it sounds), but I was reading best practices on Android development/watching Google IO videos and somewhere found this advise

Answer (score 0):

We have found that you can't get hold of the MvxListView in the OnCreateView method to bind to the ViewModel.

We have managed to get it work work if you use OnActivityCreated method and bind your ViewModel to the View there.